# objective-c How to prevent an action while a thread is being executed

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I've been using Multithreading for a while I thought I got it but my program is crashing now.

I have a method that has to download data for the server and access memory depending on the data, that process takes long, so I execute it from a secondary thread like this:

```
-(void)showPeople{
   dispatch_queue_t pintaOcupantes = dispatch_queue_create("Pinta Ocupantes", NULL);
   dispatch_async(pintaOcupantes, ^{
     //BUNCH OF CODE
     [self isPersonIn:jid];
     //MORE CODE that include methods calling isPersonIn

});
```

Inside that block there's isPersonIn. It crashes if I press too fast the button that executes showPeople. IsPersonIn is something like:

```
-(int)isPersonIn:(XMPPJID *)jid{
    int i = 0;
    for(NSDictionary *card in self.listaGente){
        NSLog(@"la jid es: %@", [card objectForKey:@"jid"]);
        NSLog(@"la jid del usuario es: %@", jid.user);
        if([[card objectForKey:@"jid"] isEqualToString:jid.user]){
           return i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

It compares a XMPPJID with an array which is a instance variable. 
isPersonIn is called several times from different methods but all the methods that call it belong to the block, so as I understand it, all the executions of isPersonIn should be serialized, FIFO, right?

But if I press the button that executes showPeople, the one containing the block, many times very fast the app crashes on isPersonIn, sometimes without any message. I can see the threads when it crashes and I see at least 2 threads with isPersonIn last in the stack, which doesn`t make sense, since the block should be executed one at a time, not several threads at the same time, right?

Any help will be very much appreaciated.

Thanks!

[EDIT]
Also the instance array, self.listaGente, is modified outside the block.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a GCD expert, but I suspect the reason you're getting multiple threads is that you're creating a new dispatch queue each time showPeople is called.

So rather than having a single serial queue with multiple blocks, I think you are ending up with multiple queues each executing a single block.

[EDIT] If the collection is modified outside of the block but during execution of the block, this could be the source of your crash. From [Fast Enumeration Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html):

> Enumeration is “safe”—the enumerator has a mutation guard so that **if you attempt to modify the collection during enumeration, an exception is raised**.

Comment: Im not an expert either, but what I know is that blocks any other thread to go in until the current queue that was created finished executing the block.
So a new queue is not created until the previous one has finished, Im right on this guys?

Comment: I've just checked the documentation and found this: "Blocks submitted to a serial queue are executed one at a time in FIFO order. Note, however, that blocks submitted to independent queues may be executed concurrently with respect to each other." So I think this is saying that FIFO is only guaranteed within a single queue. 

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW14

Comment: @KazR is correct. Block execution is FIFO only in respect to the serial dispatch queue they running on. Since you make a new queue every time showPeople is called, each block is run on its own dispatch queue. Note that the "Pinta Ocupantes" name is just for convenience when debugging and does not actually force the queues to be the same. Also, you are leaking memory here because dispatch queues need to be manually released and are not handled by ARC.

Comment: But in this case it's always the same queue, it has the same name. If that's not being serialized then there's no other way it's ever serialized.

Comment: as @UIAdam stated, the string you supply when creating the queue is only a name for debugging purposes, so each call to dispatch_queue_create will create a new queue.

Comment: and how can I get the behaviour I expect?

Comment: Create the queue once store the dispatch_queue_t returned, and then use that in subsequent calls to dispatch_async.

Answer (score 0):

In this case protecting the array, that was provoking my app to crash, fixed the problem.

using:

```
@syncronized(theArray){
    //CODE THAT WILL ACCESS OR WRITE IN THE ARRAY
}
```

This way threads will stop before if there's a thread already executing that code, like a mutex or semaphore